# Centering Menu Bar CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, web

I am designing a website, but having issues getting the menu bar to center correctly. I have done a lot of research on the web, but can't seem to figure it out. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

The html code that deals with links.

```
<nav>   
        <ul>
            <li><a href = "index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href = "shorthornHerdsires.php">Shorthorn Herdsires</a></li>
            <li><a href = "shorthornCows.php">Shorthorn Cows</a></li>
            <li><a href = "herefordHerdsires.php">Hereford Herdsires</a></li>
            <li><a href = "bullSale.php">Bull Sale</a></li>
            <li><a href = "cowSale.php">Cow Sale</a></li>
            <li><a href = "history.php">History</a></li>
            <li><a href = "contact_process.php">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

This is my css style sheet.

```
nav{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

nav ul {
    padding: .7em;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    background: #a4d25d;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5), 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3) inset; 
    border: 3px solid black;
    /* added*/


}
nav li {
    float:left;
}

nav a {
    float:left;
    padding: .8em .7em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    font: bold 1.1em/1 'trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #black #BF7530;
    background: #FF8700;
 }

nav a:hover, nav a:focus {
    outline: 0;
    color: #black;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    background: #FFDB73;
}

nav a:active {
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3) inset;
}

nav li:first-child a {
    border-left: 0;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;            
}

nav li:last-child a {
    border-right: 0;
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;            
}
```

Comment: can you describe what you want it to look like?  "center correctly" could mean a number of different things.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/TLVhe/

Comment: Sure, I want it to center horizontally. Currently, the menu is on the left side of the screen.

Comment: Floated elements cannot be centered.

Comment: I'd suggest starting with that example and tweaking it to get the look (colors, borders, padding, ...) you want.

Comment: [An article on centering elements](http://designshack.net/articles/css/how-to-center-anything-with-css)

Comment: @BillyMoat Something more like this... http://red-team-design.com/cool-css3-navigation-menu/

Comment: @JeremyCook Should I remove the float?

Comment: @user3356901 - Not sure what's different from my example to the one you've liked to?

Comment: Hey everyone, I ended up using @okia's code below and it works. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Great! You can signal that you appreciate someones assistance by upvoting answers.

Comment: @JeremyCook I wish I could, but StackOverFlow says "I need 15 reputation", which I don't have yet!

Comment: Ah yes, of course. Well I'm pretty sure you can still mark one answer as "the answer". Glad you got some help.

Comment: Cool, didn't realize I could mark "the answer." Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here one solution to center your menu :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BuqlA/

```
nav{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
    padding: .7em;
    list-style: none;
    background: #a4d25d;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5), 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3) inset; 
    border: 3px solid black;

    display: inline-block;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possibility, depending on exactly what you are looking for.
This uses `display:inline-block` for the `a` and `li` elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/jdWgE/

Answer (score 0):

You can use aplying `display: inline-block;` to the `<ul>` with `text-align: center;` to the `parent`, like this:

```
nav{
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Hope it is that what you need

**DEMO here**: http://jsfiddle.net/verber/fENS4/4/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind supporting only modern browsers that recognize and support the flexbox specification, you can use that to your advantage. You only need to change the styles for `nav` and `nav ul`:

```
nav{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

nav ul {
    padding: .7em;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none;
    background: #a4d25d;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5), 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3) inset; 
    border: 3px solid black
}
```

The trick is to set `<nav>` to use flexbox display, and instruct it to justify its content to the middle/center. I have removed the `float: left` declaration for the list because that is not needed.

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/z6KVk/